# Low level function call from child contract to parent failing

Tags: solidity, react

I have developed an app for my hiring portfolio. I am having trouble calling a function in the parent contract from the child contract. This parent function works when called directly.

In JS:

```
buyItem =async(ind) => {
const { costs, address } = this.state;
//var amount = web3.utils.toWei('${costs[ind]}', 'wei'); How to pass cost variable here?
//await this.ItemManager.methods.triggerPayment(ind, 1, this.accounts[0]).send({ from: this.accounts[0] });
await this.web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: address[ind], from:this.accounts[0], value: costs[ind]});
let data =  await this.ItemManager.methods.productData(ind).call({ from: this.accounts[0] });
amounts[ind] = data[2];
this.setState({quantities: amounts});
```

}

In the child contract:

```
 receive() external payable {
    ////require(msg.value == priceInWei, "Sorry, partial payments are not supported");
    require(paidWei % priceInWei == 0, "Sorry, partial payments are not accepted!");
   
    paidWei += msg.value;
    numberPaid = msg.value/priceInWei;
    require(quantity >= numberPaid, "Sorry, there is not enough stock to fulfill this order");
    quantity -= numberPaid;
     
    (bool success, ) = address(parentContract).call{value:msg.value}(abi.encodeWithSignature("triggerPayment(uint256, uint256, address)", index, numberPaid, msg.sender));
    require(success, "Payment processing failed, please contact the owner");
}
```

In the parent contract:

```
 function triggerPayment(uint _Ind, uint qty, address buyer) public payable {
    ProductSale product = products[_Ind]._product;
    require(address(product) == msg.sender, "Only items are allowed to update themselves");
    ////require(products[_Ind]._quantity >= qty, "The quantity you have ordered exceeds the available quantity");
    paymentAuth[buyer]._transaction[paymentAuth[buyer]._buyerIndex]._itemStep = ItemSteps.Paid;
    products[_Ind]._quantity -= qty;
    paymentAuth[buyer]._transaction[paymentAuth[buyer]._buyerIndex]._quantity = qty;
    emit ItemStep(_Ind, buyer, paymentAuth[buyer]._buyerIndex, qty, uint( paymentAuth[buyer]._transaction[paymentAuth[buyer]._buyerIndex]._itemStep)); //removed: uint(items[_index]._step)
    emit ProductStep(_Ind, address(product),uint(products[_Ind]._quantity));
    paymentAuth[buyer]._buyerIndex++;
}
```

I get **no errors in the console** when paying the child contract; however, the quantity **does not** update (this is taken from the parent). When I call triggerPayment directly the quantity **does** update. The child has a balance of 0, could this be the problem as it may need to pay gas to pass the amount along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the space in `encodeWithSignature` argument. It should be:

```
abi.encodeWithSignature("triggerPayment(uint256,uint256,address)", index, numberPaid, msg.sender)
```

Comment: That actually worked, thank you! Its always the simple mistakes

Comment: you are welcome.